# How to use NativeScript plugin through typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nativescript

I'm using EddyVerbruggen's Firebase plugin(https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase) in one of my NativeScript application.

Also, I'm the first time using TypeScript in this project. I've setup everything as it's given in their documentation. But, can't able to understand how to use their code in TypeScript.

Ex:

```
 var firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");

  firebase.init({
    persist: true // Allow disk persistence. Default false.
  }).then(
      function (instance) {
        console.log("firebase.init done");
      },
      function (error) {
        console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);
      }
  );
```

Can't able to understand how to use above code in Typescript. Any documentation or tutorial link will be a great help.

Regards

Comment: What's the problem? All JS code should work fine in Typescript as it's a superset. If you just want some general info on using Typescript and Nativescript together, then I'll post an answer with that info.

Answer (score 2):

All JavaScrip is valid TypeScript, there is not need for any additional changes. The above JavaScript calls are 100% valid in TypeScript and should not lead to any errors or warnings.

Here is a quick quote from [www.typescriptlang.org](http://www.typescriptlang.org):

> Types enable JavaScript developers to use highly-productive
>   development tools and practices like static checking and code
>   refactoring when developing JavaScript applications.
>
> Types are optional, and type inference allows a few type annotations
>   to make a big difference to the static verification of your code.